# C++ using a static const class member in a template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constants, static-members

So I have this c++ code which I have written for c++0X. It used to compile in MSVC 2012, but now I switched to MingW64 4.8.1 because I was dissatisfied with the lack of C++11 support in MSVC. The following is part of some code which implements a simple Entity/Component System.

This is the error I get:

> if(e->components.find(T::ID) == e->components.end())
>
> undefined reference to
>   `EL::Position3DComponent::ID' ELEntityManager.h   /Elementium/Elementium  line
>   64    C/C++ Problem

which is related to using T::ID...

Here is some further explanation of what I used to use this code for in MSVC 2012:

In every component, I have a static const ELComponentID member which is initialized to the component's id. This is used because I need to easily get the entities which have a certain component, so I'm using a multimap in the ELEntityManager whose key is ELComponentID and whose value is a unique_ptr containing the ELEntity who has such a component.

In the ELEntity class, I use an unordered_map whose key is ELComponentID and whose value is a unique_ptr containing the ELComponent in question.

Yes it does take up a little more memory, but I do this mainly for access speed.

file ELEntityManager.h:

```
//Includes
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include "ELEntity.h"
#include "ELComponent.h"

namespace EL{

class ELEntityManager
{
public:

//...

template<typename T> void addComponent(std::unique_ptr<ELEntity> e, std::unique_ptr<ELComponent> c)
{
    if(c == nullptr || e == nullptr)
        return;
    if(e->components.find(T::ID) == e->components.end())  //***** <-- This is where I get the error.
    {
        //...
    }
    //...
}

//...

private:
//******************************************
// Private data members
//******************************************
    std::multimap<ELComponentID, std::unique_ptr<ELEntity> > entities;
};    

};// End namespace
```

file ELEntity.h:

```
//Includes
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include "ELComponent.h"

namespace EL{

class ELEntity
{
    friend class ELEntityManager;

//...

private:
//******************************************
// Private data members
//******************************************
    /**The map of ComponentIDs with their components.*/
    std::unordered_map<ELComponentID, std::unique_ptr<ELComponent> > components;
};

};// End namespace
```

file ELComponent.h:

```
//Includes
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "ELMath.h"


namespace EL{

/**
* Component IDs.
*/
enum ELComponentID {
    LogicalDevice = 1,  // Start the enum at 1.
    Viewport,
    Position3D,
    Position2D,
    Orientation,
    PhysicsRK4
};

/**
* Base component class.
*/
struct ELComponent
{
};

/**
* Position3D component, derives from ELVector3D in EL::Math.
*/
struct Position3DComponent: public ELComponent, EL::Math::ELVector3D
{
    static const ELComponentID ID = Position3D;
};

//...
```

then I have this in main.cpp as a test (with all the required includes, etc...):

```
EL::ELEntityManager em;

std::unique_ptr<EL::ELEntity> e(new EL::ELEntity());
std::unique_ptr<EL::Position3DComponent> obj(new EL::Position3DComponent());

obj->x = 1.0;
obj->y = 2.0;
obj->z = 3.0;

em.addComponent<EL::Position3DComponent>(std::move(e), std::move(obj));
```

Now my question is, am I doing something wrong which is gcc specific, is the T::ID not supported in gcc/mingw, or has anything changed in the final c++11 implementation which wasn't in for MSVC 2012?

How do I fix this error? If it can't be done anymore in c++11, or if there's a bug in gcc, can I do this any other way?

Thanks a lot in advance for your replies! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think GCC is right. From the code you posted, it seems to me you are not providing a *definition* for your static data member.

Since you are passing `T::ID` in input to `std::unordered_map::find()`, which takes its argument *by reference*, you are odr-using `ID` (ODR stands for One Definition Rule, and odr-using means, in short, that the compiler needs to know the address of that object).

Since the address of the static data member is needed, but no definition at global namespace is provided, you end up with an unresolved symbol error from the linker.

Per paragraph 9.4.2/3 of the C++11 Standard:

> If a non-volatile const static data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class
>   definition can specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer* in which every *initializer-clause* that is an *assignment-expression*
>   is a constant expression (5.19). [...] The **member shall still be defined
>   in a namespace scope if it is odr-used (3.2) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not
>   contain an initializer**.

Therefore, to solve the problem, just add a definition at namespace scope in a `.cpp` file (or in a header included by just one `.cpp` file):

```
const ELComponentID Position3DComponent::ID;
```

Comment: Doing as you said and adding const EL::Position3DComponent::ELComponentID ID; at global namespace (or const Position3DComponent::ELComponentID ID; at EL namespace) results in the following two errors:

1-'ELComponentID' in 'struct EL::Position3DComponent' does not name a type

2-Type 'EL::Position3DComponent::ELComponentID' could not be resolved

Comment: @JPDuchesne: I'm sorry, I mixed things up a bit while writing. I edited the answer and provided the correct syntax.

Comment: I figured I'd add this right after the Position3DComponent struct in ELComponent.h, but then I get a multiple definition of 'EL::Position3DComponent::ID' error everywhere I have included ELComponent.h (main.cpp, ELEntity.cpp, ELEntityManager.cpp). Any insight?

Comment: @JPDuchesne: Yes, you cannot add that in a header file included in multiple translation units (i.e. cpp files), or you will violate the One Definition Rule. You should put the definition in one and only one .cpp file (or put it in a header which is included by one and only one .cpp file).

Comment: Ah you're right :) So it does fix my compile errors! But I do get a crash at runtime when executing my addComponent method.. maybe it's messed up, I'll verify and get back to you with an accepted answer :)